# DateTime and UniversalTime

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I am confused with the DateTime component of .net. The server is running in UTC +4 and my clients are in different timezones. So the time on the server is in UTC+4 mode. I've already tried to cast it to UniversalTime and to send it in ToBinary before sending it to client, but on client machine the code looks like

```
if ((Program.license.EndDate.ToUniversalTime() 
    - DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()).TotalMinutes <= 5)
{ 
    //dosomething 
}
```

still works wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the a web or winforms application?

Comment: Are you storing the Program.license.EndDate using the server's local time zone? or are you storing it as UTC?

I would store it as UTC if that is what you are going to be comparing against. Then you can use DateTime.UtcNow on the client to get the local time in UTC for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know the DateType of the DateTime being sent from the client (Local, Universal, or Unspecified).  If you try to cast an Unspecified type as universal, from what I understand, it will be handled as local time. (Someone please correct me if I am wrong.)

Best practice with server/client dates and times is to ***always*** use UTC.  In .Net use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`.